# File not found error when using cyberduck CLI for OneDrive

Tags: powershell, windows-10, onedrive, cyberduck

I want to upload encrypted backups on OneDrive using [cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/) to avoid local copys. Having a local file called `file.txt` I want to upload in folder `Backups` from OneDrive root, I used this command:

`duck --username <myUser> --password <myPassword> --upload onedrive://Backups .\file.txt
Transfer incomplete…
File not found. /. Please contact your web hosting service provider for assistance.`

It's not even possible to get the directory content using `duck --username <myUser> --password <myPassword> --listonedrive://Backups` command. This also cause a `File not found` error.

#### What I'm doing wrong?

I exactly followed the [documentation](https://trac.cyberduck.io/wiki/help/en/howto/cli#Usage) and have no clue why this is not working. Cyberduck was installed by using chocolately, current version is `Cyberduck 6.6.2 (28219)`

Comment: Have you tried the CMD shell? Powershell's got different parsing, so maybe it's messing up parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just testing this out, it looks like OneDrive sets a unique identifier for the root folder. You can find that by either inspecting the value of the `cid` parameter in the URL of your OneDrive site or I found it by using the following command

```
duck --list OneDrive:///
```

Note, having three slashes is important. It would appear the first two are part of the protocol name and the first specifies you want the root. The result should look like a unique id of some sort like this: `36d25d24238f8242`, which you can then use to upload your files like:

```
duck --upload onedrive://36d25d24238f8242/Backups .\file.txt
```

Didn't see any of that in the docs... just tinkering with it. So I might recommend opening a bug with duck to update their docs if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use the full path to the file, it looks like it is just complaining about not finding the file to uploads so could be you are in a different directory or something so it needs the full path to the source file.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to have any effect: Still getting `File not found. /.` error :/